# statsmodels error when importing numpy.core.numerictypes : AttributeError: module 'numpy.core' has no attribute 'numerictypes'

Tags: python, numpy, statsmodels, attributeerror

AttributeError: module 'numpy.core' has no attribute 'numerictypes'

I can't understand where this error is coming from.  I have uninstalled and reinstalled statsmodels and numpy.

[image: jupyter notebook image error]

Comment: this happened to me a couple of times before. try updating your numpy `conda update numpy`

Comment: I had to uninstall numpy, statsmodels -- then reboot and reinstall the packages.  Then it worked.